# Certain image textures not applying right

Tags: modeling, texturing

Currently, I am trying to apply an image texture to the eyes of this model, yet when I add the image into the nodes, the texture will either come out misaligned and not be where it should, or just appear black like in the picture. (The problem has occurred on other models as well) The model I am currently using was imported from SFM using Crowbar, and the textures were imported using VTF

[image]

Edit. I am unsure of whether or not the UV is misaligned in any way, so I have attached an image with the entire UV shown.

[image]

Comment: "Applying right" is not a universal concept. When you use an image as texture on a material, the default coordinates are set by the UV maps. Most likely the UV maps are not set the way you need them. Please [edit] your question and show an image that shows said UVs.

Comment: There we go. I'm still fairly new to Blender, so I'm sorry if I'm slow to catch onto things.